# Is there any alternative for SQlite Database for Blackberry?

Tags: database, blackberry

I am working on one application and i want to use that application in all OS of Blackberry (From 4.2 and upward).

But problem is that i want to store the Data in any Lightweight DB rather then persistence Data Store.

Please give me the name or Link from where i can get the detail about the Light weight Database (Excepting Sqlite and UltraLite ).

Answer (score 1):

Going back that far in your OS requirements, you may not have much of a choice other than using the Persistence Store directly, or writing something with a light SQL interface on top of the Persistence Store.

Even support for SQLite is something of a new thing in the BlackBerry world.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more Database the you can implement in Blackberry that is RMS(Record Management Store)
  [RMS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-rms/)